# Uncaught Error: No data returned for operation `<mutaion name>`, got error(s)

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-relay

I am using React-Relay. I am doing a mutation which returns errors which is totally fine but at the end I am getting following error in console which is related to react-relay library.

```
Uncaught Error: No data returned for operation `CreateUserMutation`, got error(s):
A unique constraint would be violated on User. Details: Field name = email

See the error `source` property for more information.
    at createError (RelayError.js:44)
    at Object.create (RelayError.js:29)
    at normalizePayload (normalizePayload.js:31)
    at Object.next (RelayModernEnvironment.js:245)
    at Object.next (RelayObservable.js:223)
    at Object.next (RelayObservable.js:561)
    at Object.next (RelayObservable.js:561)
    at RelayObservable.js:492
    at _subscribe (RelayObservable.js:609)
    at RelayObservable.subscribe (RelayObservable.js:315)
    at Object.next (RelayObservable.js:376)
    at Object.next (RelayObservable.js:561)
    at RelayObservable.js:484
```

Any idea how we can catch/avoid it?

[image]

Comment: ever find a solution?

Comment: Actually seems this is a known issue: https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/2070

Comment: Did you look at this comment? https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/2070#issuecomment-325656413